# КостюмИрованный или костюмирОванный?

Tags: орфоэпия

**КостюмИрованный или костюмирОванный**?
На сайте три словаря дают три разных ответа. Так как правильно поставить ударение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Раньше правильно было костюмирОванный (не слышала ни  разу в устном употреблении), костюмИрованный - не рекомендовалось. Сейчас некоторые словари уже фиксируют как норму второй вариант. А на "Грамоте" четко написано - костюмирОванный - устаревшее

Большой толковый словарь
КОСТЮМ**И**РОВАННЫЙ; (устар.) КОСТЮМИР**О**ВАННЫЙ, -ая, -ое; -ван, -а, -о.

Русское словесное ударение (Зарва)
костюм**И**рованный, -ан, -ана, -ано, -аны

Comment: На грамоте орфоэпический словарь даёт только костюмИрованный, толковый и так, и так, а орфографический только костюмирОванный. Причём если брать авторитетность источников, то она у этих словарей как раз обратная

Comment: С каких эо пор орвографичкский словарь стал авторитетным в разгорах об орфоэпических нормах?
Заметьте, я об авторе даже не говорю.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно костюмирОванный, гофрирОванный, пломбирОванный. Интересно, что эти слова включаются в современные олимпиады по русскому языку разного уровня. Поэтому в школе мы уделяем им особое внимание.

Comment: Этих слов нет в фиксированном списке к ЕГЭ именно потому, что ударение неоднозначное. Все меняется... ЗАрва, которому Вы доверяете (Вы часто ссылаетесь на него) даёт костюмИрованный.